# Prevent iPhone to sleep

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiapplication

I using accelerometer in my app and i'm using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;` to prevent the device to sleep. It works fine, but this way the screen is always on full bright, there is a way to prevent the device to sleep and keep the energy economy mode on? 
When `idleTimerDisabled` is stetted to NO the device enter in the energy economy mode before sleep, i just want to prevent the device to sleep and keep the energy economy. There is a way to do that?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961783/dim-iphone-screen-but-dont-let-it-sleep

Comment: This is on the border of Apple guidelines and your app may be rejected for doing this without very good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a property of `UIScreen` instances, `brightness`, that is likely what you want.  Check out the documentation of `UIScreen`'s `brightness` property [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006903-CH3-SW19).

Try:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: 0.3];
```

**NOTE:** As I was posting, DarkXphenomenon posted a link to an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1961783/1292061) whose asker gave the exact same solution.  DarkXphenomenon is quick on the draw.

Comment: Hum, this will do =) Thank you!