# iOS screen dim bug solutions

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscreen

Some days ago i asked this question: [Prevent iPhone to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486036/prevent-iphone-to-sleep)

Then i found out the bug that can't let the delegate methods change the screen bright back to normal when the home button is pressed. I looked around and saw some "solutions" involving imageView and other stuff. My view have some buttons and a tabBar, i think a imageView over these buttons will not be a great idea, i need the buttons working all the time.

Anyone have some solution or alternative for this bug?