# How do I prevent iOS device from locking while on a particular screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app includes a 'Sleep Mode' that is initiated by pressing a button on the main screen. While on this screen I want to prevent the phone from locking automatically but still allow auto dimming. If the user leaves the app by manually locking their device or pressing the home button they should be able to navigate back to the app and have their device remain unlocked. What is the best way to accomplish this in objective-c?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668840/prevent-iphone-auto-lock-but-permit-screen-dimming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following code to prevent device getting auto locked

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: Please don't ask for points. It's pretty much frowned upon here.